# Android API 19 support AlertDialog black border instead of shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

**Android 5.1** renders this dialog correctly, but **kitkat 4.4.4** and below show black border instead of shadow.

It seems that **android:windowBackground** is responsible for that. I have tried different `drawables` for background, tried **Genymotion** and **Android SDK emulators**, tried older support libraries without success. I did not set any styles for this dialog. It is shown from `Fragment`.

The only error i see in logcat - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

[image: AlertDialog black border]

Comment: I'm using DialogFragment and it seems to be connected to the problem, standalone AleertDialog.Builder works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly my fault, i was changing window attributes to set dialog width dynamically, but it seems to be the wrong way:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lp.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, width, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
alert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

It is necessary to obtain attributes using alert.getWindow().getAttributes() instead of creating new instance.

Answer (score 1):

The border, round corners and margin are all defined by android:windowBackground.

Try to add the below line to your java file:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```